# log4j2 mapping xml to properties file

Tags: xml, properties, log4j2, properties-file

I have a log4j2 configuration written in XML, however I need to make them in properties format (key and value) for arrangement purposes. I cannot seem to map nested conditions in xml to properties.

Here is my XML configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="DEBUG">
    <Properties>
        <Property name="log-path">./var/log/reporter/</Property>
    </Properties>
    <Appenders>

        <RollingFile name="RollingFile" fileName="${log-path}/reporter.log"
            filePattern="${log-path}/reporter-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}-%i.log">
            <PatternLayout>
                <pattern>[Reporter] [%level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] [%logger{36}] %msg%n</pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
            <Policies>
                <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="1" modulate="true" />
                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="20 MB" />
            </Policies>
            <DefaultRolloverStrategy max = "1000">
                <Delete basePath="${log-path}">
                    <IfFileName glob="reporter-*.log" />
                    <IfAny>
                      <IfLastModified age="90D" />
                      <IfAccumulatedFileSize exceeds="2 GB" />
                    </IfAny>
                </Delete>
            </DefaultRolloverStrategy>
        </RollingFile>

    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Logger name="root" level="debug" additivity="false">
            <appender-ref ref="RollingFile" level="debug" />
        </Logger>
        <Root level="debug" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="RollingFile" />
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

And here is my non-working properties configuration mapping:

```
appender.rolling.type = RollingFile
appender.rolling.name = RollingFile
appender.rolling.fileName = ${logpath}/reporter.log
appender.rolling.filePattern = ${logpath}/reporter-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}-%i.log
appender.rolling.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.rolling.layout.pattern = [Reporter] [%level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] [%logger{36}] %msg%n
appender.rolling.policies.type = Policies
appender.rolling.policies.time.type = TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy
appender.rolling.policies.time.interval = 1
appender.rolling.policies.time.modulate = true
appender.rolling.policies.size.type = SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy
appender.rolling.policies.size.size=1KB
appender.rolling.strategy.type = DefaultRolloverStrategy
appender.rolling.strategy.max = 1000
appender.rolling.strategy.action.type = Delete 
appender.rolling.strategy.action.basepath = ${logpath}
appender.rolling.strategy.action.NestedConditions.type = IfALL
appender.rolling.strategy.action.NestedConditions.PathConditions.type = IfFileName
appender.rolling.strategy.action.NestedConditions.PathConditions.glob = reporter-*.log
appender.rolling.strategy.action.NestedConditions.NestedConditions.type = IfAny
appender.rolling.strategy.action.NestedConditions.NestedConditions.time.type = IfLastModified
appender.rolling.strategy.action.NestedConditions.NestedConditions.time.age = 90D
appender.rolling.strategy.action.NestedConditions.NestedConditions.size.type = IfAccumulatedFileSize
appender.rolling.strategy.action.NestedConditions.NestedConditions.size.age = 2GB

logger.rolling.name = root
logger.rolling.level = debug
logger.rolling.additivity = false
logger.rolling.appenderRef.rolling.ref = RollingFile

rootLogger.level = debug
rootLogger.appenderRef.stdout.ref = RollingFile
```

Comment: Mohamed, were you able to map your xml to properties? I am kind of in a similar situation..

Comment: Unfortunately not, we have used properties file instead eventually.

Comment: If you used properties file, then how did you manage multiple nested conditions? If there is only one nested condition, then elifyilbasi's answer would match, but if there are two or more, then the resulting property would look like a duplicate of the previous nested condition and thus it won't work.

Answer (score 0):

It a little bit late but you can gain insight from the link https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/master/distribution/src/main/resources/config/log4j2.properties

It has all the conditional property usages you needed.

Answer (score 0):

the file has moved link has been updated to https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/master/distribution/src/config/log4j2.properties